# Do Django aggregate functions use indexes?

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, django-models

I have a django model with a huge number of instances (rows) in the database (PostgreSQL).
Then I'm aggregating a decimal field of the model and averaging it.
My question is, **would it speed up the aggregation process to set and index for that field?**

Example of what I'm doing:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lines_per_page = models.DecimalField()

Blog.objects.all().aggregate(x=Avg('lines_per_page'))[x]
```

Would then make the following change improve the aggregation?

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lines_per_page = models.DecimalField(db_index=True)

Blog.objects.all().aggregate(x=Avg('lines_per_page'))[x]
```

As I said my database is huge, only the table of the model I'm working with occupies ~6GB.

Comment: This is not Django specific: it will create a query that looks like `SELECT AVG('lines_per_page')) FROM blog`. It is up to configuring your database to take advantage of indexes, etc.

Comment: No, an index on `lines_per_page` column won't speed up the calculation of the average. The index is used in searches (Django `filter()` method), in this case your db has to read all the rows anyway to calculate the average. If you filter your blogs by `name`, then adding an index on the `name` column will definitely speed up those queries.

Comment: Okay that answer it then. Thanks @dirkgroten

Comment: maybe you want to store a calculated avg somewhere every time the table is updated, so that it can be retrieved faster. E.g. in a `post_save()` signal. This would slow down the code saving an object, which may or may not be something you find acceptable. Or, if it's not critical that the average is exactly up-to-date, you can consider calculating the average regularly (with a schedule, repeating job) and saving it somewhere.